# Commerce coupon only one coupon active at a time

Tags: commerce

I have 3 types of coupons on my site, 2 of them are contrib(fixed amount and percentage amount) and 3rd one is custom(pretty much copy of percentage). 
  I need to make sure, that only one coupon of custom type can be active at given time. Which hooks should I use to make sure that when one coupon of custom type is made active, the other one becomes not active?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is as follows.
1. Check if entity created is a coupon and that coupon type is the one im checking using hook_entity_insert and hook_entity_update
2. Check if coupon changed or inserted has been put active if yes then load all other coupons of right type and turn them inactive